Postfix mail flow confusion
i have question about the flow that an incoming email message goes trough the Postfix processes.
According to Postfix documentation here:
https://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html
it seems to be that the message received via the smtpd daemon will first be processed by the configured milters and after that by the cleanup process before placed inside the queue.
So - the path should be smtpd -> milters -> cleanup -> queue ...
Looks fine, however i wonder why my log file looks like this - as you can see, the cleanup process log line comes BEFORE the lines written by the milters (opendkim,opendmarc)
2024-08-13T13:21:36.990607+03:00 mail postfix/smtp-p25/smtpd[1185150]: F1CA9147E41: client= ...
2024-08-13T13:21:36.996145+03:00 mail postfix/cleanup[1185147]: F1CA9147E41: message-id= ...
2024-08-13T13:21:37.033494+03:00 mail opendkim[36599]: F1CA9147E41: ... not internal
2024-08-13T13:21:37.033677+03:00 mail opendkim[36599]: F1CA9147E41: not authenticated
2024-08-13T13:21:37.044464+03:00 mail opendkim[36599]: F1CA9147E41: DKIM verification successful
2024-08-13T13:21:37.044608+03:00 mail opendkim[36599]: F1CA9147E41: s=smtp-out d=... a=rsa-sha256 SSL
2024-08-13T13:21:37.265707+03:00 mail opendmarc[243532]: F1CA9147E41: SPF(mailfrom): ... pass
2024-08-13T13:21:37.268392+03:00 mail opendmarc[243532]: F1CA9147E41: ... pass
2024-08-13T13:21:37.310273+03:00 mail postfix/qmgr[1185008]: F1CA9147E41: from=<...>, size=1648, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
2024-08-13T13:21:37.327950+03:00 mail postfix/lmtp[1185198]: F1CA9147E41: to=<...>, ...
2024-08-13T13:21:37.328497+03:00 mail postfix/qmgr[1185008]: F1CA9147E41: removed

It looks like the milters are called asynchronously?
